# How to plot a path from equations of motion of a point in wxMaxima?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I have the following equations of motion of a point:

```
x:3*sin(4*t);
y:2*cos(4*t);
```

I already created a vector:

```
r:[x,y];
```

and did some operations but I don't know how to plot the path (the result should be an ellipse).

I tried various commands and only this gave me something similar to what I want to achieve:

```
load(draw);
draw2d(parametric(x,y,t,0,10));
```

But the result is strange:

[image]

Is there a way to get a proper plot in form of an ellipse in wxMaxima in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `draw2d(parametric(...))` is not applying adaptive subdivision to get a smoother plot; it's just sampling from a fixed grid. You can say `draw2d(nticks = <large number>, parametric(...))` to get a somewhat smoother plot, but the problem doesn't go away.

Try `plot2d([parametric, x, y, [t, 0, 10]])` -- I find that gives a nice smooth plot.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I just used wxplot2d instead of plot2d to get a plot within the same window.